# Deploying the ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am creating my first ASP.NET Web API. Created the application, build them and ran the application by calling the URL like http://localhost:35432/api/Sample?id=1&id=83  and returns the JSON file as response.

But I dont see anything  with respect to this application on the IIS manager. Where do I find them or do I have to set up something. I am not sure how we will be deploying the application from DEV to TEST server.

Comment: This is Off Topic as it's not related to programming, however, by default Visual Studio uses IIS Express to debug, that's why you don't see it under IIS.

Comment: I didnt know if this is off topic question. I am not sure how I will be seeing the application on the IIS manager. do we need to move them from IIS express to the IIS manager

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698(v=vs.100).aspx